# Repetition of array elements in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat

I have a MATLAB array and want to make a repetition based on the number of array elements. Below is the example that I want.

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

If I want 7 elements, the result is

```
aa = [2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 6]
```

Or if I want 5 elements,

```
aa = [2, 4, 6, 8, 2]
```

Is there any MATLAB function which makes these kind of result?

Comment: Take a look at the [repmat](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function. I'm not sure but it might help you. :)

Comment: @V.L. Thanks for comment! I just checked repmat but it looks like only integer times of repetition is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple option will be to use a temporary variable for that:

```
a = [2 4 6 8];
k = 7;
tmp = repmat(a,1,ceil(k/numel(a)));
aa = tmp(1:k)
```

First, you repeat the vector using the smallest integer that makes the result larger than `k`, and then you remove the excess elements.

If you do that many times you can write a small helper function to do that:

```
function out = semi_repmat(arr,k)
tmp = repmat(arr,1,ceil(k/numel(arr)));
out = tmp(1:k);
end
```

Comment: Yes. As your comment, I repeat the vector using the smallest integer (with floor function) and reduce the size. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 6):

You can use "modular indexing":

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8]; % data vector
n = 7; % desired number of elements
aa = a(mod(0:n-1, numel(a))+1);
```